# Not displaying the selected JSON data

Tags: json, swift, parsing

Very new to JSON.
Manage to get the JSON data from the given api but just not able to display the selected data. Apparently the JSON parsing part is not working?

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let baseURL = "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=MYR_JPY"

    @IBOutlet weak var amountToConvert: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayMYRtoJPY: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rateLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GetcurrencyPair(url: baseURL)
    }

    func GetcurrencyPair(url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(baseURL, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    print("Sucess! Got the Currency Pair")
                    let currencyPairJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    print(currencyPairJSON)

                    self.updateRateTicker(json: currencyPairJSON)
                } else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    self.rateLabel.text = "Connection Issues"
                }
        }
    }

    func updateRateTicker(json : JSON) {
        if let tempResult = json["results"].int {

            print(tempResult)
            rateLabel.text = String(tempResult)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the output of this statement  `print(currencyPairJSON)`

Comment: 2018-12-22 13:59:56.212527+0900 CurrencyConvert[10267:804031] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
Sucess! Got the Currency Pair
{
  "query" : {
    "count" : 1
  },
  "results" : {
    "MYR_JPY" : {
      "fr" : "MYR",
      "val" : 26.604641999999998,
      "to" : "JPY",
      "id" : "MYR_JPY"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Read** the JSON. Except the value for key `count` there is no `int` value at all in the record.

Probably you are looking for the value for key `val` which is in the dictionary `MYR_JPY` and is a `Double`

Try

```
func updateRateTicker(json : JSON) {
    if let tempResult = json["results"]["MYR_JPY"]["val"].double {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(tempResult)
            rateLabel.text = String(tempResult)
        }
    }
}
```